# Boneh/Franklin Identity based encryption with Tate pairing

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings, identity-based-encryption

Boneh/Franklin developed an identity based encryption scheme based on the Weil Pairing. This algorithm has also been standardised in IEEE P1363.3 .

I know that this algorithm can also be implemented with a type 3 Tate pairing. But I could not find a paper or standard where this is clearly described.

Does anyone know a good reference? Ideally, this should be some kind of standard like IEEE, ISO, ANSI, etc.